# How to use Lit by and Lit with properly?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

1. The room is lit by/with candles.
2. The house is lit by/with electricity.

What should be the appropriate preposition for each sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong here as both are acceptable. Here are two links by Google Ngram on how often each phrase is used: [by/with candles](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lit%20by%20candles%2Clit%20with%20candles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clit%20by%20candles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clit%20with%20candles%3B%2Cc0) and [by/with electricity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lit%20by%20electricity%2Clit%20with%20electricity&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clit%20by%20electricity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clit%20with%20electricity%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

You generally use **by** to show how you do something, and **with** to show what you use to do it.

- lit **with** candles  (what you use)
- lit **by** candlelight  (how it's lit)

Electricity is a little different because "electricity" can mean the how or the with.

- lit **by** electricity   (how it's lit)
- lit **with** electrical power  (lit with electricity)

[Reference](https://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2014/04/02/using-the-prepositions-by-with-english-grammar-lesson/#:%7E:text=We%20use%20by%20to%20show%20how%20someone%20does%20something%20but,found%20this%20caf%C3%A9%20by%20accident.)

Comment: I think you are making a distinction here that fulent spesker do not normally make. And I don't see any bsis for this distinction even in theory. Can you cite any source for this distinction between "by" and "with"?

Comment: I already cited a source at the bottom where it says "Reference."